# CURL showing "No required SSL certificate was sent" eve

Tags: ssl, curl, ssl-certificate, mtls

I am using a CURL command from WINDOWS.
I have posted the command below.
I have also posted the results of the command.
It appears to me, the server is terminating the connection before sending the certificate.
But I could wrong.
Any ideas why the certificate is not being sent?

```
curl -v --cert C:\Users\myFolder\Downloads\hs_test_cert.pem --key C:\Users\myFolder\Downloads\hst_test_key.pem https://myAPIGEEhost.apigee.net/MyBackendName_CCDA_API?apikey=MyAssignedAPIKey

 *   Trying 00.00.00...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to myAPIGEEhost.apigee.net (00.00.00) port 443 (#0)
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with myAPIGEEhost.apigee.net port 443 (step 1/3)
* schannel: checking server certificate revocation
* schannel: sending initial handshake data: sending 203 bytes...
* schannel: sent initial handshake data: sent 203 bytes
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with myAPIGEEhost.apigee.net port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: failed to receive handshake, need more data
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with myAPIGEEhost.apigee.net port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: encrypted data got 4096
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 4096 length 4096
* schannel: encrypted data length: 4026
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 4026 length 4096
* schannel: received incomplete message, need more data
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with myAPIGEEhost.apigee.net port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: encrypted data got 964
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 4990 length 5050
* schannel: a client certificate has been requested
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with myAPIGEEhost.apigee.net port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 4990 length 6014
* schannel: sending next handshake data: sending 133 bytes...
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with myAPIGEEhost.apigee.net port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: encrypted data got 274
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 274 length 6014
* schannel: SSL/TLS handshake complete
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with myAPIGEEhost.apigee.net port 443 (step 3/3)
* schannel: stored credential handle in session cache
> GET /MyBackendName_CCDA_API?apikey=MyAssignedAPIKey HTTP/1.1
> Host: myAPIGEEhost.apigee.net
> User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
> Accept: */*
>
* schannel: client wants to read 102400 bytes
* schannel: encdata_buffer resized 103424
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 0 length 103424
* schannel: encrypted data got 421
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 421 length 103424
* schannel: decrypted data length: 361
* schannel: decrypted data added: 361
* schannel: decrypted data cached: offset 361 length 102400
* schannel: encrypted data length: 31
* schannel: encrypted data cached: offset 31 length 103424
* schannel: server closed the connection
* schannel: schannel_recv cleanup
* schannel: decrypted data returned 361
* schannel: decrypted data buffer: offset 0 length 102400
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Date: Mon, 27 Sep 2021 18:22:21 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 231
< Connection: close
<
<html>
<head><title>400 No required SSL certificate was sent</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<center>No required SSL certificate was sent</center>
<hr><center>server</center>
</body>
</html>
* Closing connection 0
* schannel: shutting down SSL/TLS connection with myAPIGEEhost.apigee.net port 443
* schannel: clear security context handle
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It appears to me, the server is terminating the connection before sending the certificate. But I could wrong.

The TLS handshake of the HTTPS connection succeeded, since otherwise the server could not have sent a HTTP response - which it clearly did.

> ```
> * schannel: a client certificate has been requested
> ```

This debug message indicates that the server requested a certificate from the client, i.e. mutual authentication. This certificate requests comes after the server has already send its own certificate to the client.

> ```
> <center>No required SSL certificate was sent</center>
> ```

While you have provided a client certificate and key on the command line none was actually send. The reason is that client certificates are not supported with SChannel in curl 7.55.1 (what you are using), see [TODO](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/curl-7_55_1/docs/TODO#L796):

```
15.1 Add support for client certificate authentication

 WinSSL/SChannel currently makes use of the OS-level system and user
 certificate and private key stores. This does not allow the application
 or the user to supply a custom client certificate using curl or libcurl.

 Therefore support for the existing -E/--cert and --key options should be
 implemented by supplying a custom certificate to the SChannel APIs, see:
 - Getting a Certificate for Schannel
   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375447.aspx
```

Better support for client certificates were added in newer version but even with the current latest (7.79. ) it is not possible to give a PEM file as cert or key with the SChannel TLS backend.

Comment: Thanks Steffen. Any idea how what utility to use to test MTLS?

Comment: @CarolineMuch: curl with OpenSSL backend would be fine.  OpenSSL by itself would be fine. Anything using it too, like Python. Browser should work also (with imported client certificate) ....